# GDB QEMU Remote target doesn't support qGetTIBAddr packet

Tags: rust, gdb, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug an EFI application in qemu with gdb. QEMU is started with -s and -S flags and gdb is started with

```
gdb ./target/x86_64-unknown-uefi/debug/application.efi
```

and qemu is targeted with

```
target remote :1234
```

GDB resonds with `Remote target doesn't support qGetTIBAddr packet`.
I verified that the efi file contains debug symbols. I can't find anything about this online so any help is appreciated.